# How do differences in spread of a condition affect life time statistics?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $y$ men are tickled yearly and $x$ women are tickled yearly. And the death rate is $d$ men or women per year.

Then the number of tickled women, $T_x$ that die per year is $T_x d_x/n_x$.

And the number of tickled women that are tickled is $T_x x / n_x2$.

And the number of untickled women that are tickled each year is $(1 - T_x / n_x) x$.

So, the rate of tickling is:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} T_x}{\mathrm{d} t} = (1-T_x /n_x) x - T_x d_x / n_x $$

Then,

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} T_x}{\mathrm{d} t} = x- x T_x /n_x - T_x d_x / n_x $$
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} T_x}{\mathrm{d} t} = x-  T_x (x /n_x + d_x / n_x) $$
$$ - \frac{\ln (x-  T_x (x /n_x + d_x / n_x))}{x /n_x + d_x / n_x} = t + c_0 $$

$$ T_x = k_0 \mathrm{e}^{\frac{-t}{x /n_x + d_x /n_x}} + \frac{x}{x/n_x+d_x / n_x}$$

and in the limit

$$ T_x = \frac{x}{x / n_x + d_x /n_x}$$

and so the proportion of tickled women will eventually reach

$$ T_x / n_x = \frac{x}{x+ d_x}$$

as well,

$$ x T_x / n_x + T_x d_x / n_x = x$$
$$  x (T_x / n_x -1) + T_x d_x / n_x = 0$$
$$  x /n_x = \frac{T_x d_x /{n_x}^2}{1 - T_x / n_x} $$

If 20% women or 2000 women are tickled each year out of a population of 10000 with a death rate of 10% or 1000 women then the amount of women that have been tickled in their life time is $T_x / n_x \approx 67\%$.

If 18% of men or 1800 men are tickled each year then $T_y / n_y \approx 64\%$.

If 1/5 women have been tickled in their life time with a death rate of 100 then 25 women per year are tickled which seems to make sense.

How do differences in spread of a condition affect life time statistics?